# what 's the problem in malloc.c 3096

Tags: c, malloc

```
> malloc.c:3096: sYSMALLOc: Assertion
> `(old_top == (((mbinptr) (((char *)
> &((av)->bins[((1) - 1) * 2])) -
> __builtin_offsetof (struct malloc_chunk, fd)))) && old_size == 0)
> || ((unsigned long) (old_size) >=
> (unsigned long)((((__builtin_offsetof
> (struct malloc_chunk,
> fd_nextsize))+((2 * (sizeof(size_t)))
> - 1)) & ~((2 * (sizeof(size_t))) - 1))) && ((old_top)->size & 0x1) &&
> ((unsigned long)old_end & pagemask) ==
> 0)' failed.
```

The error i encountered when i am running my c program which uses integer  3D pointers and normal int variables

Comment: You probably trashed your heap some time prior to calling malloc.

Answer (score 4):

There's no problem in malloc, the error is somewhere in your own code.

Comment: I found the solution to the problem...... actually it happens when any memory blocks are missed or tried to access when memory is not created. It also happens when you created by a int data instead of int* etc... and tried to access of int* type

Answer (score 2):

Most likely that you  overwrote the memory just before or after a block of memory previously allocated.  Or you freed a block and then wrote to it anyway.

It's also possible that you allocated too much memory without freeing it, or too little (malloc doesn't like negative numbers).  Usually these last 2 won't cause an assertion, but every platform has it's own quirks.

There are so many ways to mess with malloc's head....

Comment: Shouldn't overallocating memory just make malloc return NULL?

Comment: malloc takes a size_t variable, so I'd congratulate you if you were able to give it a negative number ;) And the assertion was obviously thrown because he overwrite some internal datastructure from what it reads.

Comment: but he could have meant to say that "malloc doesn't like negative numbers", why is left to the imagination and logical inference: a negative numbers to malloc is a very huge number, that is a problem.

Comment: @Shin But there are no negative numbers from mallocs point of view - sure huge positive numbers will be a problem (although it's clearly defined what happens in that case and that's not "an assertion fails") but malloc will never deal with negative numbers. That's like saying malloc will handle float arguments correctly because those are also converted to size_t as well (are they? Think so but not 100% sure, not a usual problem that ;) )

Comment: so we can say malloc has problems with floats too. Just a matter of philosophy: the fact that malloc does not see at all floats or negative numbers it means that its a problem using malloc with them, so those types are disliked by malloc (it refuses them at the point that it does not know/see them at all). Just kidding, but it seems the comment was lost in a semantic/philosophic details.